# Doctrine error during upgrading Symfony 3.4 to 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new at Symfony stuff but I have to try to upgrade some aplication from Symfony 3.4 to 5.4.
During moving code of repositories I've run into problem with autowiring them.
I've read that it should be done by switching them to ServiceEntityRepository and making them a constructor.

So I made all of them something like below:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use App\Entity\ApiBackup;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class ApiBackupRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, ApiBackup::class);
    }
```

This however resulted with new kind of error which I wasn't able to find:

**Invalid repository class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\EntityRepository'. It must be a Doctrine\ORM\Exception\EntityRepository.**

Any ideas how to get rid of such error?

edit: services.yml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity, Repository,Tests,Kernel.php,Query, DataForm}'

    App\DataForm\:
        resource: '../src/DataForm/*'
        public: true
        shared: false
    App\Helpers\ZoneStatsService:
        public: true

    App\Helpers\CalendarEnabledService:
        public: true

    App\Helpers\MourningEnabledService:
        public: true

    App\Helpers\FormStepResolver:
        autowire: true
        public: true
    App\Helpers\ApiErrorHandler:
        autowire: true
        public: true

    App\Helpers\DnsApiHelper:
        autowire: true
        public: true

    App\DataForm\Partner:
        autowire: false

    App\DataForm\MenuBloki\MenuBloki:
        autowire: false

    App\DataForm\MenuBloki\MenuBlokiFile:
        autowire: false

    App\Helpers\ResourceLoaderService:
        arguments: ['@service_container', '%memcache_expiration_value%']

    jms.js.extractor:
        class: App\Translation\JavaScriptTranslationExtractor
        tags:
            - { name: jms_translation.file_visitor}
```

Comment: Can you provide the service.yml configuration?

Comment: Never saw that error before.  Almost seems like a lack of a use statement sort of thing.  Pure speculation but I suspect you have some version mismatch issues.  Consider creating a new 5.4 project and just sort of compare composer.json files.  Also, you don't actually need to autowire your repositories if your app is not injecting them.  You can just exclude src/Repository and move on.

Comment: Well I really guess should've add services.yml to this question

Comment: Since you have already converted your repositories to ServiceEntityRepositories try removing `Repository` from the list of excluded directories.  Not positive but you might need them to be services for things to work.  And after you do that, confirm the service's existence with `bin/console debug:container ApiBackupRepository`